# When can an HMONITOR be associated with multiple physical displays?

Tags: winapi, multiple-monitors

In one MSDN article, I read the following:

[HMONITOR and the Device Context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144968.aspx)

> Each physical display is represented by a monitor handle of type HMONITOR.

However, another article seems to contradict that statement:

[GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd692950.aspx)

> A single HMONITOR handle can be associated with more than one physical monitor.

So my question is: under what circumstances will an `HMONITOR` be associated with multiple physical monitors?

Comment: I don't see the contradiction. To supplement your first quote: *"Each physical display is represented by a monitor handle of type HMONITOR. Two or more physical displays can be represented by the same handle."* If you are trying to use the `HMONITOR` as an ID for a physical display, things will break. Knowing the answer to your question, under which circumstances an `HMONITOR` can be associated with multiple physical monitors is not going to help.

Comment: To answer the question, at a guess I'd say maybe when one display is set to mirror another one, or when you have hardware that makes multiple monitors look like a single big one to Windows.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I didn't think about mirroring - thanks, I'll test it. The "single big one" is [the virtual screen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145136\(v=vs.85\).aspx), which is a higher-level concept.

Comment: No I'm talking about something like a hardware video splitter. Windows sees one big monitor (the splitter), the splitter splits the video to two or more monitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An HMONITOR can be associated with multiple physical/virtual monitors like this:

[multi-monitors share a same HMONITOR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50rso.jpg)

When select 'Duplicate these displys' instead of 'Extend these displays', two physical/virtual monitors can share one HMONITOR, or in other word, they are totally overlapped. In this case, you may get two IDDCX_MONITORs(physical or virtual monitors) but only one HMONITOR.

Actually, I'm finding way of mapping between IDDCX_MONITORs and HMONITORs:[Map a IDDCX_MONITOR to a HMONITOR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59773566/map-a-iddcx-monitor-to-a-hmonitor)